# Using return in foreach not echo with medoo

Tags: php, foreach, medoo

This is my example of my code i need to get work...

If i use " echo '...'; " everything is ok but if i use " return '...'; " i get only one record. The problem i dont want to use echo is i get all results on the top of my page. i need to use return because i call this function somewhere else on my page.

Thanks!

```
    public function showForum()
{

    $cats = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM forum_cats ORDER BY cat_order ASC")->fetchAll();

    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
        return '<table class="table forum table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="cell-stat"
                    style="background-image: url(\'\'); background-size: 50px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;"></th>
                <th>
                    <h3>' . $cat['cat_name'] . '</h3>
                </th>
                <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">Topics</th>
                <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">Posts</th>
                <th class="cell-stat-2x hidden-xs hidden-sm">Last Post</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-question fa-2x text-primary"></i></td>
                <td>
                    <h4><a href="#">Frequently Asked Questions</a><br>
                        <small>Some description</small>
                    </h4>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">9 542</a></td>
                <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">89 897</a></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">by <a href="#">John Doe</a><br>
                    <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 months ago</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>';

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, because `return` ends the execution of the function. Instead in your loop, set the string to an array item and after the loop, return the array. You can then later echo out.

Comment: I edited my comment to suggest storing each in an array, another option is to continuously concat the strings and just return the final string.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions @JonStirling! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all the data you want to return in a string, and later return the string:

```
public function something() {
    $result = ""; // Create empty string

    foreach($array as $val) {
        $result .= "something"; // Add something to the string in the loop
    }

    return $result; // Return the full string
}
```

An alternative (since you already have an array) would be mapping the array to your string values and returing the imploded the array like so:

```
public function something() {
    return implode('', array_map(function($val) {
        return "something";
    }, $array));
}
```

Comment: what about this: http://paste.md-5.net/roxirenudu.coffee , i get the wrong forums now...

Comment: You would need to set `$display_forums = "";` *inside* the second foreach, but actually you don't need two variables at all! You can just keep concatenating to your first one.